# How to save a scipy dendrogram as high resolution file?

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, cluster-computing, hierarchy, dendrogram

I have a matrix which has 600 different labels. Therefore, it is really big file; and I couldn't see these labels very well, when I created a figure to cluster my data. How should I create a high resolution file and save it?

I already tried below code.

```py
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hcluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

SimMatrix = mainTable

distVec = ssd.squareform(SimMatrix)
linkage = hcluster.linkage(1 - distVec)
dendro  = hcluster.dendrogram(linkage, leaf_rotation=90., leaf_font_size=0.5,)

matplotlib.pyplot.savefig('plt.png', dpi=520, format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

I am trying to get big high resolution file, it can be png or jpeg.

I got below image as figure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4aqX.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your resolution, but the size of the image (or the size of the lines). Since i do not know how to change the linewidth in the dendogram plot, i will just go with the straight forward solution to make a HUGE image.

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as hcluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

SimMatrix = np.random.random((600,600))
SimMatrix = SimMatrix+SimMatrix.T
SimMatrix = np.abs(SimMatrix-np.diag(np.diag(SimMatrix)))

distVec = ssd.squareform(SimMatrix)
linkage = hcluster.linkage(distVec) #Changed here do NOT C+P back
plt.figure(figsize=(150,150))
dendro  = hcluster.dendrogram(linkage, leaf_rotation=90., leaf_font_size=0.5,)

plt.savefig('plt.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.savefig('plt.jpg', format='jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

The saved images looked bad for me, when i opened them, and only zooming in cleared up the problem. But the inlined plot in the jupyter notebook looked good, so maybe you only have to play with the format a bit.

This is probably not the best solution, but for me it worked. Hope someone else more competent can give you the correct solution too!

Ps.: Do not try to save these with 520 DPI, would break the pyplot.

Comment: Thanks, the main problem is actually about figure size. Now, I can see better. Do you have any different idea about displaying this kind of tree? 

I was also thinking to implement like "folders in folders". Maybe, you can also suggest something about it.

Comment: You can try a circle dendogram (i do not know how to make those) but with 600 labels that should be still huge to be able to read it.

If you need only the structure and not the labels exactly, you can try the truncating option of the dendogram plot.

If you need the exact labels for the different groups, i would recommend to just programmatically get the links from the linkage matrix and match it with the labels.

Sorry, but for 600 instances i have really no better idea.